# Proper way to null check Vue object with "__proto__" and/or "__ob__" property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, null-check

I would like to know a quick and clean way to check if objects with just `__ob__` or `__proto__` properties are empty. Now I have to "guess" a value inside my object and null check that instead of the object itself. Example:

```
const myObject = objectFromDb.innerValue ? objectFromDb : mockObject;
```

I would love to write this instead:

```
const myObject = objectFromDb || mockObject;
```

but it will return objectFromDb even if the values have not yet been retrieved. I'm fine with using a ternary statement instead if the `||` one, but I'm not happy with having to null-check an inner object. I'm sure there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a reason `objectFromDb` itself cannot be `null` until it's time to assign a real value?

Comment: `__proto__` is not an own data property. It's a deprecated, inherited accessor.

Comment: Try `Object.keys(objectFromDb).length > 0`? Not sure how Vue / your database treats `__ob__`.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough what you mean. It looks like you describe empty reactive object, a screenshot from console could clarify this. Then the answer is to use Object.keys like suggested above, or Lodash isEmpty, or else. This is not specific to Vue.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I guess my question could be a duplicate, but I think the fact that the object had `__ob__` and `__proto__` makes it a little different since I straight up ignored that question when I found it, thinking it was a different problem. Anyways @Bergi your solution worked :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Object.keys(objectFromDb).length > 0
```

(thanks to comment from Bergi)